# Ruby on Rails: slim form select filter first item of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I met a problem with slim of RoR when render an select box that filter the 1st item of array.

```
          .col-sm-3
            .form-group
              label #{ t '.status' }
              = f.select :/* what i need */, options_for_select(User::Paper.statuses, params[:q][/* what i need*/] : nil), {:include_blank => true}, class: 'input-sm form-control'

          // ...

          tbody
              - if @present?
                - @users.each do |user|
                  tr
                    td = user&.papers&.first&.status
```

I tried `paper_first_status` or `paper_status` but it didn't work. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already: use plural for array and filter by attribute. Ignore `first`.

```
       .col-sm-3
        .form-group
          label #{ t '.status' }
          = f.select :papers_status_eq, options_for_select(User::Paper.statuses, params[:q][:papers_status_eq] : nil), {:include_blank => true}, class: 'input-sm form-control'

      // ...

      tbody
          - if @present?
            - @users.each do |user|
              tr
                td = user&.papers&.first&.status
```